FCM push notification MESSAGE_DELIVERY status data does not exported to linked BigQuery
I am using Firebase to send Web push notificationI have integration BigQuery with my Firebase project. Also created sync to export Web push notification logs into BigQuery dataset. Notification logs are getting synced but only event MESSAGE_DELIVERED is not exported in BigQuery.
I have explored firebase documentation and found the link here and here which explain how to enable it but I don't have much idea how and where add this code to enable MESSAGE_DELIVERED status.
